# UICollectionView as subview in a UICollectionCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a working UICollectionView with one section containing some elements. The collection view has one column and scrolls vertical. The amount of rows depend on how many elements are in the data source (rows = elements_in_section).

Now, I would like to add a second section into the UICollectionView. In that seconds section I would like to have a single row of images and I would like to scroll horizontal (colums = elements_in_section).

AFAIK you can not set different flow directions per section, so my idea was to add a single cell in the section and add a UICollectionView as as subview. So basically I habe a UICollectionView in a UICollectionView.

My only Problem is that if I do so I can not scroll (left/right) in the inner UICollectionView. I can only scroll (up/down) the outer UIScrollView.

It works flawless if you add a UICollectionView into a UITableView as you can see here (https://github.com/DahanHu/DHCollectionTableView)

**So my question is: should UICollectionView in a UICollectionView work out of the box or do I have to do some extra work to make it work?**

*In the below image there are three row and not one - but i hope you get the idea*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the real problem was that I did use a plain `View` for the cell in the Nib file. As soon as I used a `Collection Cell View` every worked as expected.